# "Is there living in space?" vs "Is there life in space?" what is the rule or convention?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds

My Russian-speaking friend recently used this one in asking me a question: "do you think there is living in space?" while using the gerund "living" in place of a noun.

To me it sounds horribly wrong--I would say: "do you think there is life in space?" or "do you think there are living things in space?" but I'm having trouble justifying this with an actual rule or convention on why.

I want to say that the definition of "living" as a gerund or noun refers to the condition of being alive and not a living thing itself, and can't be a replacement for the word "life", but I'm not confident that this is really the reason.

Comment: I would say *living being* instead of *living thing*.

Comment: They don't mean the same. Check a dictionary for *living* and for *life*. Tell us what you found. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are equally grammatical. It's not about grammar, it is entirely about meaning. Your hunch is exactly right. You cannot replace *life* with *living* for the same reason you can't replace it with *beer* or *The Simpsons*: it just doesn't mean the same thing.

In addition, there is a morphological phenomenon that actually makes *life* vs. *living* special as opposed to *life* vs. *beer* or *life* vs. *car* or what have you. It's called ["blocking"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28linguistics%29). We already have the word *life* to mean "life", so its existence blocks the noun *living* from getting created with the exact same meaning. If it is to get introduced and get any traction (which it did), then only to cover a meaning different from that of *life* (and so it does).

So you *can* say "living in space", "make a life", "get a living". They are just as grammatical as "life in space", "make a living", "get a life". They just won't mean the same thing. Because, well, that's what different words do. That's why we have them in the first place. Otherwise they'd be the same word.

All of this is just as true of Russian, of course. You can't just go around replacing *жизнь* with *житие, живность, живот* or *животное*.